# How can I get count in SQL without using count Method

Tags: sql

I want to Know, how SQL Count function works.

If I want to get Count in SQL, I write

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

But How can I get **Count** Without using **COUNT()** function.

May be its answer will be helpful for others.

Comment: Actually I want to know how internally existing functions call

Comment: Return Row count

Comment: When we create our own function we write sql statement

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: @jarlh Okay no issue

Comment: If you want to know the number of rows, simply use the `count()` _function_...

Comment: What is written inside **Count** Function

Comment: I know what **count** function do

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about internal workings of mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon, how do you know it's MySQL?

Comment: @ jarlh true enough but applies to any sql.

Comment: `1)` MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc, etc will all implement it differently.  `2)` The database engines are written in a different language.  `3)` SQL is *"declarative"* and not *"imperative"*, so why do you care how COUNT() is implemented?

Comment: @MatBailie My question was that are they use SQL statement for existing functions or write in other language . Thanks your first point is good

Comment: SQL is ***declarative***.  SQL is never executed.  SQL can't run on any existing processor.  SQL is read by a database engine, which also checks database statistics, then determines the best/cheapest way to go about solving the problem described by the SQL.  That solution is called an `explain plan` or an `execution plan`.  Those plans are not written in SQL.  The code used to implement `COUNT()` is not written in SQL.  It's all probably a mix of C++ and C, but could really be Any ***imperative*** language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT() Function is the best way to get the number of records. So nobody goes for custom queries or functions to Get the records count.

But you can also try this (For **SQL Server** Databases)

```
SELECT 
MAX(SeqNo) FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnName DESC) SeqNo 
        FROM TableName
) Q
```

Or if you are performing a select Query, then the number of rows returned or affected by your query will be stored in a variable @@ROWCOUNT

```
select * from TableName

select @@ROWCOUNT
```

The 2nd select will return the Count

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with unknown dbms. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh This is for SQL server